# Find the probability that $ab+c=23$, where $a, b, c$ are prime numbers less than $30$

Tags: combinatorics

$a, b, c$ are integers randomly chosen from the set of prime numbers less than $30$. what is the probability that $ab+c=23$?

My approach:

We can select $3$ numbers from $10$ numbers in ${10\choose 3}$ = $120$ ways

Now, $ab+c= 23$ is possible for this combinations of $(a,b,c)= (2,3,17)$, $(2,5,13)$ and $(3,7,2)$.

So, probability= $\frac{3}{120}= \frac{1}{40}$.

Is it correct?

Comment: The way you select numbers imply the order of the triple (a,b,c) doesn't matter, but it does since a,b and c play different roles. Also, it implies we can only choose the same number once, is this the case ?

Comment: $a$ $b$ and $c$ are not necessarily different, so there are $3^{10}$ ways, not $\binom{10}{3}$ ways.

Comment: ok, i got it. but if numbers are different, is it ok?

Comment: No, because there are $6$ combinations, not $3$. And also because there are $\binom{10}{3}\cdot3!$ ways for selecting therm, not $\binom{10}{3}$.

Comment: I see four different ways to interpret this and 4 different answers.  (Although one of my interpretations is very unlikely.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ are not necessarily different, so there are $3^{10}$ ways for selecting them.

There are $7$ combinations in which $ab+c=23$:

- $2,2,19$
- $2,3,17$
- $2,5,13$
- $3,2,17$
- $3,7, 2$
- $5,2,13$
- $7,3, 2$

Therefore, the probability that $ab+c=23$ is $\frac{7}{3^{10}}$

---

If the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ are necessarily different, then there are $\binom{10}{3}\cdot3!$ ways for selecting them.

There are $6$ combinations in which $ab+c=23$:

- $2,3,17$
- $2,5,13$
- $3,2,17$
- $3,7, 2$
- $5,2,13$
- $7,3, 2$

Therefore, the probability that $ab+c=23$ is $\frac{6}{\binom{10}{3}\cdot3!}$

Answer (score 0):

Must the numbers be different or not?  Can you pick the three numbers and rearrange them how you like or are the picked in order?

First off: from the primes these are the only ways to get $ab+c = 23$

$2*2 + 19; 2*3 + 17; 2*5 + 13; 3*7 + 2$.

The first two digits may be transposed.

Case 1) $a$ is drawn first, then $b$, the $c$ and you chose to see if $ab + c = 23$

There are $10!/7! = 10*9*8 = 720$ ways to choose and there of the three $2*3 + 17; 2*5 + 13; 3*7 + 2$ there are $2$ ways to draw the first two numbers.  So $6$ acceptable outcomes.

So $6/720$ or $1/120$.

Case 2)  You draw 3 numbers and see if they can be arranged.

There are ${10 \choose 3} = 120$ ways to choose them.

Possible solutions are $2*3 + 17; 2*5 + 13; 3*7 + 2$.  Order doesn't matter and has been taken into account when we chose via ${10 \choose 3}$.

So $3/120 = 1/40$.

(If we hadn't accounted for multiple orders, we'd have had $720$ total bu each of the three results could have been drawn in 6 possible orders so $3*6/720 = 1/40

Case 3) You draw $a$, put it back, draw $b$, put it back, draw $c$. See if $ab + c =23$

There are $10^3$ ways to draw and of them there are:

$(2,2,19), (2,3,17),(3,2,17),(2,5,13),(5,2,13),(3,7,2),(7,3,2)$

so $7/1000$.

d) Draw with replacement but allow to choose order. (Not likely this is the intended interpretation.

There are $1000$ ways to draw.

The combinations are $(2,2,19)$ and there are $3$ ways to draw it.  The other three-- $(2,3,17),(2,5,13),(3,7,2)$ have six ways of arranging.  That's $3 + 3*6 = 21$.

so $21/1000$